# Run react hook inside variable for-loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Here's the use case. Our individual AJAX calls are behind a hook (we use apollo hooks). However, sometimes we need to make a variable number of calls (a variable for-loop). An initial AJAX calls determines how many variable calls to make to another endpoint. Unfortunately, this code does not run (React runtime error):

https://jsfiddle.net/dm3b2Lgh/

I've looked at this other question but the given approach does not work: [Why can't React Hooks be called inside loops or nested function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53906843/why-cant-react-hooks-be-called-inside-loops-or-nested-function)

Is there a way to make this work?

```js
function useInitialAjaxCall() {
    const [result, setResult] = React.useState(0);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const resultSize = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    Promise.resolve().then(() => setResult(
            resultSize
    ))
  }, [])
  return result;
}

function useMockAjaxCall(i) {
    const [result, setResult] = React.useState();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    Promise.resolve().then(() => setResult(i));
  }, [i])
  return result;
}

function useMakeNCalls(n) {
   return [...Array(n)].map((_, i) => useMockAjaxCall(i));
}

function useCombineAjaxCalls(n) {
    const resultArray = useMakeNCalls(n);
    const resultCombined = React.useMemo(() => {
    return resultArray.reduce((total, cur) => total + cur, 0);
  }, [resultArray])
  return resultCombined;
}

function Hello(props) {
  const initial = useInitialAjaxCall();
  const count = useCombineAjaxCalls(
        initial
  );
  return (
  <div>
  <div>{initial}</div>
  <div>{count}</div>
  </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: So... what is the question?

Answer (score 2):

The [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53906843/1176601) was asking about a fixed for-loop:

> if we call useState inside a loop where the number of iterations doen't change over the time

However, in your code, `useInitialAjaxCall()` will return *undefined* during first render (because `useEffect` is asynchronous - it will be executed AFTER the first render).

Then, `useCombineAjaxCalls(undefined)` will call `useMakeNCalls(undefined)` which will call `useMockAjaxCall(0)`, calling `useState` only once.

In the end of first render, `initial` will be *undefined* and `count` will be *NaN*.

Assuming `resultSize` is different from 1, in the next render, your code will try to call `useState` different number of times than 1, which is not possible as explained in the original question.

It is NOT possible to "Run react hook inside variable for-loop" - but you can create 1 state that is an array.

Comment: there was a bug in the code that i threw together---i updated to always return a number on initial call. Still the same error though

Comment: Are you saying that it is *NOT* possible to do what we're trying to do? There's no way around this except to manually do n AJAX calls (no hooks)?

Comment: I am saying it's not possible to have variable number of hooks. I am not sure what you are trying to do, but you can always use fixed number of hooks to fetch arbitrary number of data, e.g. `const [data, setData] = useState([]); Promise.all(xxx).then((results) => setData(results))`