# create useState in a loop based on array possible?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

```
    const columns = ['task', 'category'];

    for (const text in columns) {
        const [text, setText] = useState();
    }
```

I wish to create multiple useState things using a loop but to join things together seem to be a problem.
What I want it to do is to create consts: task, setTask | category, setCategory

Comment: What I'm seeing here is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/254800). [Using `useState` in a loop is never the solution](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level), but without explaining the goal behind your question, we can't really help more than saying not to do this.

Comment: Thats definetely not the right way, as already mentioned. You have to provide more information, so we can give you some guidance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't React Hooks be called inside loops or nested function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53906843/why-cant-react-hooks-be-called-inside-loops-or-nested-function)

Comment: @EmileBergeron Thanks for finding and sharing the answer. It worked perfectly for me and resolved a critical issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`const [text, setText] = ...` is just a [deconstructing assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), you can store the result of `useState(..)` (an array with two elements) however you want, for example:

```
const columns = ['task', 'category'];
const state = {};

for (const prop of columns) {
  const resultArr = useState();
  state[prop] = {
    val: resultArr[0],
    fn: resultArr[1]
  };
}
```

And you can use the results like this:

```
<button onClick={() => state.task.fn('new value')}>{state.task.val}</button>
```

But as [@EmileBergeron mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59415946/create-usestate-in-a-loop-based-on-array-possible#comment105019359_59415946), there doesn't seem to be any reason to use `useState` like this. There is definitely a more conventional way of solving the problem that you're facing.

Answer (score 6):

Check this out:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Explicitly mentions:

> **Only Call Hooks at the Top Level** Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions. Instead, always use Hooks at the top
>   level of your React function. By following this rule, you ensure that
>   Hooks are called in the same order each time a component renders.
>   That’s what allows React to correctly preserve the state of Hooks
>   between multiple useState and useEffect calls. (If you’re curious,
>   we’ll explain this in depth below.)

Comment: Is there any harm in calling hooks in loops that iterate over the same array every time? Seems like manually unrolling the loop in that case is pointless

Comment: yes, since the "loop" is a variance - then the number of times hooks is called is variant. So, it wont work.

Answer (score 1):

Under the hood, `useState` relies on a linked-list-type nested data structure in the fiber. Each time you call `useState` that structure is "unwrapped" to get the data associated with the next hook call.

[This is a good article](https://medium.com/the-guild/under-the-hood-of-reacts-hooks-system-eb59638c9dba) that goes into depth about how hooks work.

In theory, so long as your loop **always** executes the same number of times, you could use a hook inside of the loop. **HOWEVER**, as other people have said here, this is not a standard way of doing things and is not advisable.

Answer (score 0):

```
const columns = ['task', 'category'];
columns.map( (column, index) => {
  let col = column;
  let setCol = column+index;
  [col, setCol] = useState(false)
})
```

This way it will give unique state for each iteration of elements in the array **columns**

Answer (score -1):

```
const [uploadAnimal, setAnimal] = useState(['cat']);

const loopFun = () => {
const arr = uploadAnimal
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  
   arr.push('DOG')
   setUploadCount([...arr])
} };
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: this answer was flagged for low quality, please better the answer with more supporting info and explanation or delete it