# Why can't I use useEffect() in a loop?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

Trying to find clarification on it. That's what an interviewer told to my friend when they were describing this hook.

Comment: Probably reading the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) section or the [Using the Effect Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) will answer that from the documentation.

Comment: The rules of hooks provide a semantic reason for why you can't use it in a loop, but the reason behind the rules of hooks is due to the fact that React hook implementations rely on the ordering of their calls within a function component in order to properly propagate state between renders.

Comment: @norbitrial awesome! thank you so much

Comment: Also, see [Why can't React Hooks be called inside loops or nested function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53906843/1218980)

Answer (score 4):

By following this rule, you ensure that Hooks are called in the same order each time a component renders. That’s what allows React to correctly preserve the state of Hooks between multiple useState and useEffect calls.

Read more here : [Rules Of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)