# Why does mapping a React hook work, but a lambda violates rule of hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, eslint

If I have a hook, e.g:

```js
const useGetSet = (label: string) => {
  const [get, set] = useState(label);
  return { get, set };
};
```

I can `map` it over an array, e.g:

```js
const labels = ['one', 'two'].map(useGetSet);
```

---

But if I expand this to a lambda, e.g:

```js
const labels = ['one', 'two'].map((l) => useGetSet(l))
```

Then it causes:

> React Hook `"useGetSet"` cannot be called inside a callback.
> React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook
> function.
> (react-hooks/rules-of-hooks) eslint

---

Why this difference, shouldn't they be equivalent?

Additionally, if this is a violation of the rule of hooks, how *should* this be done?

[Full working example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/map-react-hooks-sqpbl?file=/src/App.tsx).

Comment: I believe ESLint has some limitations on what it can easily identify as fine and what is considered a violation.

Comment: Though loops can be used with hooks (provided the iteration count is hard-coded), they're usually unjustified. See: [Why can't React Hooks be called inside loops or nested function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53906843/1218980)

Comment: I'm surprised that the first one is allowed.  You are playing with dangerous territory using a hook in a `map`.   It is only ok in this case because `['one', 'two']` is a fixed array.  If you were mapping an array that could change length then you would have major problems.

Comment: I think my assumption was right about the limitation of the rule implementation, see [the source code](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/3b870b1e0912c076c450bee261d8dbb181de673c/packages/eslint-plugin-react-hooks/src/RulesOfHooks.js#L495-L506).

Comment: Re: *how should this be done*, you might get differing opinions but mine is to pass the whole array to a hook `useGetSetArray`: https://codesandbox.io/s/map-react-hooks-forked-7ggzv?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's bad in both cases, but ESLint isn't picking up the first case.

You can see this by changing the labels array at run-time. If you increase or decrease the length it blows up (because an unexpected number of hooks was called, as per the exception), if you don't it doesn't re-render as expected. [See here](https://codesandbox.io/s/map-react-hooks-forked-wvu9m?file=/src/App.tsx) for an updated version of your demo.

(The reason that the rule exists is because under the hood, hooks need to be called in the same order every time. Obviously, if the number of hooks varies between renders then the order changes.)

In your specific case, because your array is fixed length and not changing then your code will work fine (no matter what the linter says). However, it's still a dangerous pattern and best avoided.

In terms of how to handle it better, if you need more than basic state management something like [`useReducer`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) would work. You can have as may labels as you like and define setter/getter actions that take the label as an argument.

Comment: You're right, and I like [Linda's implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66142914/why-does-mapping-a-react-hook-work-but-a-lambda-violates-rule-of-hooks#comment116939047_66142914) as a replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Let analyze the two scenarios:

```
const labels = ['one', 'two'].map(useGetSet);
```

In this case the `useGetSet` is called inside the hook is called "inside custom React Hook function".

```
const labels = ['one', 'two'].map((l) => useGetSet(l))
```

In this case the `useGetSet` is called inside an anonymous function, so the "rule of hooks" is broken.

So basically:

In the first scenario: Hook > call of the hook

In the second scenario: Hook > anonymous function > call of the hook

Related to the last question:

> Why this difference, shouldn't they be equivalent?

No, they are not equivalent.

In the first case the callback function reference is the function named, by you, `useGetSet`.

In the second case the callback function reference is a new function, defined anonymously.

An interesting explanation about why this rule is so important can be found in the documentation, in particular in this section:

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level

But also consider that there are cases when it is safe to disable the linter rule, as explained in depth here:

[Why can't React Hooks be called inside loops or nested function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53906843/why-cant-react-hooks-be-called-inside-loops-or-nested-function)

Comment: no, the rule is broken in both cases - the linter just can't tell

Comment: Well, I agree with you in one point: the hook is not used in a proper way. But I do not agree with you when you say "the rule is broken in both cases", let me try to explain. As explained in MDN the map function call the callback "in order". Now the rule described in the documentation explain that "By following this rule, you ensure that Hooks are called in the same order each time a component renders". So, at the end, the hook is actually called in the same order since we are talking about a constant.I would really appreciate if you can edit my answer to provide the best possible answer.

Comment: I think the talk we are doing can bring, to our knowledge, a huge benefit.

Comment: 'Call the hooks in the same order' isn't the rule, it's a fundamental requirement that allows Hooks to work. The rule is 'call Hooks at the root level of your component, not in loops or conditional statements'. The rule exists to minimise accidental bugs caused by violating the fundamental requirement.

Answer (score 0):

In this example useGetSet is the callback.

`const labels = ['one', 'two'].map(useGetSet);`

In this example your calling the hook inside the callback so the error makes sense. This answer covers pretty nicely why the rule exists: [Why can't React Hooks be called inside loops or nested function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53906843/why-cant-react-hooks-be-called-inside-loops-or-nested-function)

`const labels = ['one', 'two'].map((l) => useGetSet(l));`

You have 2 options here:

1. If you need to call the hook inside of a callback but the hook is not rendering anything then you need to create a new hook e.g https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-cache-zti5f?file=/src/TestComponent.jsx .
2. If the lambda is rendering smth at the end then you can create a new component
   e.g https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-currying-pe15r?file=/src/TestComponent.js.