# How do I create a dynamic function name for useState?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am trying to add `useState` hooks from an array of names, but it doesn't seem to work the way I thought it would work.
Does anyone have an idea on how I can achieve this?

```
let f = {
    get: { },
    set: { }
};

for (let field of fields) {
    const [f.get[field], f.set[field]] = useState(menu[field]);
}
```

and the error I am getting atm:

```
imports/ui/admin/Menu.jsx:128:10: /home/csi/csi/imports/ui/admin/Menu.jsx: Unexpected token, expected "," (128:10)

  126 |     };
  127 |     for (let field of fields) {
> 128 |         const [f.get[field], f.set[field]] = useState(menu[field]);
      |                 ^
  129 |     }
  130 | 
  131 |     const submit = e => {
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't declare fields of an object with `const`, what you can do is `const [temp1, temp2]= useState(menu[field]);f.get[field]=temp1;f.set[field]=temp2;` However I'd recommend you to reconsider your approach and store an array of values in a single state variable

Answer (score 0):

You can use useState inside loops only if you ensure that Hooks are called in the same order each time a component renders. That’s what allows React to correctly preserve the state of Hooks between multiple useState and useEffect calls.

See this ans for better clarification [Learn Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53906843/why-cant-react-hooks-be-called-inside-loops-or-nested-function)

Answer (score -1):

For starters, React hooks **SHOULDN'T** be used in conditional statements and loops as they depend on uniform and deterministic call order. Checkout [The rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) to get more insight about that topic.

Furthermore, `useState(menu[field])` returns the state variable and the setter function. Your code obviously doesn't work because it is syntactically incorrect. You can use dynamic variable names by either storing the whole state in a single object:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({property: value});

const alterState = (property, value) => {
    setState(state => {...state, [property]: value});
}
```

or using a `reducer`.