# React: Can I create a dynamic number of states in a reusable component based on props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a side project where I conditionally want to ask the user a series of questions based off their responses. I this order:

Step 1. I ask the user if they have specific account/membership
Step 2. If yes I display a series of questions if they have a rating within that account/membership
Step 3. If yes, I display an input asking them for the specific rating

To achieve this I have a parent component that asks the initial questions (step 1). I have a reusable child component is conditionally displayed for each question from step 1 (step 2) and each question is derived from props. I then have a second reusable component that is conditionally displayed by step 2 that asks for a rating and its wording is also derived from props (step 3)

My challenge is that in step 2 I would like my component to have n numbers of states where n is the size of an array that I pass down to it, so that I can track whether I should show each question for step 3. Is there a way to do this, or is there a more elegant solution? I could in theory hard code each state at the top of this component tree and then pass the state as props, but I am thinking there is a more elegant way to do this.

My code is as follows:

Initial form (step 1)

```
export default function ChessForm() {
    const [FIDE, setFide] = useState(false)
    const [USCF, setUSCF] = useState(false)
    const [Chesscom, setChesscom] = useState(false)
    const [LiChess, setLiChess] = useState(false)


    return (
        <Form>
            <p>Please fill out the below form</p>
            <Form.Group>
                <Form.Label className='mx-2'>Do you have a FIDE membership?</Form.Label>
                <Form.Check inline label='Yes' value={true} name='FIDE' type='radio' className = 'mx-2' name='FIDE'  onClick = {()=>{setFide(true)}}/>
                <Form.Check inline label='No' value ={false} name='FIDE'  type='radio' className = 'mx-2' defaultChecked  onClick={()=>{setFide(false)}}  />
            </Form.Group>

            {FIDE && <MembershipForm inputs={['standard', 'rapid', 'blitz']} name='FIDE'/>}

            <Form.Group>
                <Form.Label className = 'mx-2'>Do you have a USCF membership?</Form.Label>
                <Form.Check inline label='Yes' name='USCF' type='radio' className = 'mx-2'  onClick={()=>{setUSCF(true)}} />
                <Form.Check inline label='No' name='USCF'  type='radio' className = 'mx-2' defaultChecked onClick={()=>{setUSCF(false)}} />
            </Form.Group>

            {USCF && <MembershipForm inputs={['regular', 'quick', 'blitz']} name='USCF'/>}

            <Form.Group>
                <Form.Label className = 'mx-2'>Do you have a Chess.com account?</Form.Label>
                <Form.Check inline label='Yes' name='Chesscom' type='radio' className = 'mx-2' onClick={()=>{setChesscom(true)}}/>
                <Form.Check inline label='No' name='Chesscom'  type='radio' className = 'mx-2' defaultChecked onClick={()=>{setChesscom(false)}}/>
            </Form.Group>

            {Chesscom && <MembershipForm inputs={['bullet', 'blitz', 'rapid', 'Daily', 'puzzle']} name='USCF'/>}

            <Form.Group>
                <Form.Label className = 'mx-2'>Do you have a LiChess account?</Form.Label>
                <Form.Check inline label='Yes' name='LiChess' type='radio' className = 'mx-2' onClick={()=>{setLiChess(true)}} />
                <Form.Check inline label='No' name='LiChess'  type='radio' className = 'mx-2' defaultChecked onClick={()=>{setLiChess(false)}} />
            </Form.Group>

            {LiChess && <MembershipForm inputs={['bullet', 'blitz', 'rapid', 'Classical', 'Correspondence' , 'puzzle']} name='USCF'/>}
        </Form>
    )
}
```

Step 2 form (reusable component)
*note I currently have a state for standard, rapid, and blitz. This is the crux of the problem. I want to have states that are dynamic based off of the props that I pass down to this component.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import {Form} from 'react-bootstrap'
import RatingInput from './RatingInput'

export default function MembershipForm({inputs, name}) {
    const [standard, setStandard] = useState(false)
    const [rapid, setRapid] = useState(false)
    const [blitz, setBlitz] = useState(false)

    const questions=inputs.map(input => {
            return (
                <>
                    <Form.Group>
                        <Form.Label className='mx-2'>Do you have a {name} {input} Rating?</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Check inline label='Yes' value={true} name={name+input} type='radio' className = 'mx-2' onClick = {()=>{setStandard(true)}}/>
                        <Form.Check inline label='No' value ={false} name={name+input}  type='radio' className = 'mx-2' defaultChecked onClick = {()=>{setStandard(false)}}  />
                    </Form.Group>
                    {standard && <RatingInput name={input}/>}
                </>
            )
        })
    return (
        <div className='ml-3'>
            {questions}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Step 3:Finally this is the third component that I want to conditionally show based off the state of the above component

```
import React from 'react'
import {Form, Container, Row, Col} from 'react-bootstrap'


export default function RatingInput({name}) {
    return (
        <Container>
            <Row>
            
                <Col><Form.Label inline>What is your {name} rating?</Form.Label></Col>
                <Col><Form.Control type='number' min ={500} max ={3200} className='w-50 h-75' /></Col>
            </Row>
            <Form.Group>
            
        </Form.Group>
        </Container>
        
    )
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't React Hooks be called inside loops or nested function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53906843/why-cant-react-hooks-be-called-inside-loops-or-nested-function)

Comment: Instead of a variable number of states, you could use a single array (or object) state.

Comment: @EmileBergeron That rules out using a for-loop as a solution but doesn't really give me a solution.